# Compare list items with a list of pairs, and output matching pairs

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv, nested-lists

I have lists that are formatted like so:

```
order_ids = ['Order ID', '026-2529662-9119536', '026-4092572-3574764', '026-4267878-0816332', '026-5334006-4073138', '026-5750353-4848328', '026-5945233-4883500', '026-5966822-8160331', '026-8799392-8255522', '202-5076008-9615516', '202-5211901-8584318', '202-5788153-3773918', '202-6208325-9677946', '203-1024454-3409960', '203-1064201-9833131', '203-4104559-7038752', '203-5013053-9959554', '203-5768187-0573905', '203-8639245-4145958', '203-9473169-4807564', '204-1577436-4733125', '204-7025768-1965915', '204-9196762-0226720', '205-6427246-2264368', '205-9028779-8764322', '206-0703454-9777135', '206-0954144-1685131', '206-3381432-7615531', '206-3822931-6939555', '206-4658913-5563533', '206-5213573-9997926', '206-5882801-0583557', '206-7158700-9326744', '206-7668862-3913143', '206-8019246-1474732', '206-8541775-0545153']


one = [['Order ID', 'Amount'], ['026-2529662-9119536', '10.42'], ['026-4092572-3574764', '10.42'], ['026-4267878-0816332', '1.75'], ['026-5334006-4073138', '17.990000000000002'], ['026-5750353-4848328', '16.25'], ['026-5945233-4883500', '1.83'], ['026-5966822-8160331', '11.92'], ['026-8799392-8255522', '8.5'], ['202-5076008-9615516', '1.83'], ['202-5211901-8584318', '1.83'], ['202-5788153-3773918', '8.08'], ['202-6208325-9677946', '11.33'], ['203-1024454-3409960', '8.08'], ['203-1064201-9833131', '1.5'], ['203-4104559-7038752', '8.5'], ['203-5013053-9959554', '9.67'], ['203-5113131-7525963', '-8.5'], ['203-5768187-0573905', '3.66'], ['203-8639245-4145958', '5.08'], ['203-9473169-4807564', '3.66'], ['204-1577436-4733125', '1.83'], ['204-7025768-1965915', '1.83'], ['204-9196762-0226720', '11.33'], ['205-8348990-1889964', '-11.33'], ['205-9028779-8764322', '6.91'], ['206-0703454-9777135', '23.84'], ['206-0954144-1685131', '22.66'], ['206-3381432-7615531', '8.08'], ['206-3822931-6939555', '11.92'], ['206-4658913-5563533', '9.67'], ['206-5213573-9997926', '3.66'], ['206-5882801-0583557', '13.92'], ['206-7158700-9326744', '27.5'], ['206-7668862-3913143', '6.58'], ['206-8541775-0545153', '1.83']]
```

What I want to do is cycle through every item inside order_ids, and if the order_id is present in one - get the "value"

So far what I have tried is:

```
with open('test.csv', mode='w', newline='') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    i = 0
    while i < len(order_ids):
        for order in order_ids:
            try:
                if order == one[i][0]:
                    value_a = one[i][1]
                    print(order, value_a)
                    writer.writerow([order, value_a])
                    i += 1
                else:
                    i += 1
                    pass
            except IndexError:
                i += 1
```

This is working somewhat - but there are 36 items inside "order_ids" and 36 lists inside "one", however only 18 rows are being wrote to my outfile.

An example of one order_id that isn't being wrote is "206-7668862-3913143", even though this clearly has a value of "6.58" inside "one"

What is stopping the rest of my rows being written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this simply with a dictionary. The `dict()` constructor will accept a nested list of pairs and create a dictionary mapping `order_id` to `amount`. Then we can just loop over the `order_ids` list, and write out any `order_id` that appears to test.csv.

**Code:**

```
import csv

d = dict(one)

with open('test.csv', mode='w', newline='') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for order_id in order_ids:
        if order_id in d:
            writer.writerow([order_id, d[order_id]])
```

**test.csv:**

```
Order ID,Amount
026-2529662-9119536,10.42
026-4092572-3574764,10.42
026-4267878-0816332,1.75
026-5334006-4073138,17.990000000000002
026-5750353-4848328,16.25
026-5945233-4883500,1.83
026-5966822-8160331,11.92
026-8799392-8255522,8.5
202-5076008-9615516,1.83
202-5211901-8584318,1.83
202-5788153-3773918,8.08
202-6208325-9677946,11.33
203-1024454-3409960,8.08
203-1064201-9833131,1.5
203-4104559-7038752,8.5
203-5013053-9959554,9.67
203-5768187-0573905,3.66
203-8639245-4145958,5.08
203-9473169-4807564,3.66
204-1577436-4733125,1.83
204-7025768-1965915,1.83
204-9196762-0226720,11.33
205-9028779-8764322,6.91
206-0703454-9777135,23.84
206-0954144-1685131,22.66
206-3381432-7615531,8.08
206-3822931-6939555,11.92
206-4658913-5563533,9.67
206-5213573-9997926,3.66
206-5882801-0583557,13.92
206-7158700-9326744,27.5
206-7668862-3913143,6.58
206-8541775-0545153,1.83
```

Comment: Instead of checking the key using `if order_id in d:`, and then getting the value with `d[order_id]`, you could use `d.get(order_id)`.